# Generator AVR Wiring Question

Tags: voltage-regulator, wiring, generator

I'm replacing the AVR of a Honda EX4500s. However, the *new* AVR came with a 4-prong coupler plus two other wires (red and white), as opposed to the *original* 3-prong coupler (just like the 4-prong, but one socket doesn't have a contact) plus a red, white, and green wire. I'd guess that the extra contact/wire in the *new* AVR is the equivalent of the separate green bullet plug on the *old* AVR, and that I could just remove, resolder, and reconnect? I don't know if this is actually electrically correct, so I'd never just try it of course (for those who will blow me up with "caution" comments before I get myself blown up).

Pics (old original first, new last):

[image: Old AVR]

[image: New AVR]

Comment: Did you ever figure it out? I'm having same issue with my ME5000s

Comment: @Thomas Clark sadly no, we ended up returning and replacing it with a more expensive one with the correct wiring. I *might* be able to find the link for the working one if you would like it.